# Radio button inside kendo grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-grid

I have radio buttons in kendo grid,
 When I click on the radio button I have changed the value of `datasource` as following

```
function radioBoxClick(e) {
    alert($(e).val());
    grid = $("#grid").data().kendoGrid;
    var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e).closest('tr'));
    dataItem.set("Markable", $(e).val());
}
```

But when I check the `dataSource` on a button click it remains with the old data. I think I didn't change the value of `dataSource` correctly. When I Google regards this I can't get any help, So any help from you guys, will be highly appreciable.

I have added demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh848/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Console shows that `set` is not a defined function. In order to update the data item, simply do this:

```
dataItem.Markable = $(e).val();
```

See here for an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexyu/fh848/4/).

Comment: Yes, When I clicks second item to not markable it gives `true,true,true,true,false` But I need `true,false,true,true,true` as alert message.

Comment: That is because of the order of items you defined your datasource. `alpha` is the last item, which is why the last one is false.

Comment: So it is actually correct, but if you need to read the data in the view order you have to read the datasource differently when you make that alert message. However, this doesn't make much sense because every time you change the sort order, your result will be different.

Comment: Can you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576331/kendo-grid-refresh-issue-in-mobile) Problem?