# Kendo grid refresh issue in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I refresh the kendo grid for every 10 seconds,  I used following code and I used the `kendo.all.min.js`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            loadData();
            intervalManager(true, TableStatus, 10000);
        });
        var TableStatus = function () {
            loadData();
        }
        var refreshorderplacedgrid;
        function intervalManager(flag, animate, time) {
            if (flag)
                refreshorderplacedgrid = setInterval(animate, time);
            else
                clearInterval(refreshorderplacedgrid);
        }
        function loadData() {
            var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: [
                            { ID: '1001', FirstName: 'Alphy', LastName: 'LastName', category: 'A', Markable: true },
                            { ID: '1002', FirstName: 'Betty', LastName: 'LastName', category: 'B', Markable: true}],
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                FirstName: { type: "string" },
                                LastName: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    sort: {
                        field: "FirstName",
                        dir: "asc"
                    },
                    pageSize: 10
                },
                scrollable: true,
                sortable: true,
                selectable: true,
                columns: [
                {
                    field: "FirstName",
                    title: "First Name"
                },
                {
                    field: "LastName",
                    title: "Last Name"
                },
                { template: kendo.template($("#isCancel-template").html()) }
            ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
        }
```

This code gives me the output like following screenshot in system chrome,

[image]

But in mobile [All devices]

It appends with the old grid, instead of rebinding like following screenshot

[image]

I dont know what is problem here, I have googled and used `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();` this code too. Nothing happend, Any help will be highly appreciable.

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: Will your datasource be dynamic in the future (ie. reading from a remote service) or will it be from a local source (ie. setting the dataSource like how you are doing it above) ?

Comment: By the way, what you're currently doing in `loadData` is reinitializing the grid over and over again, which is wrong and gives you unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: My `datasource` is dynamically loading from server for every second, That why i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@gitsitgo 's comment, I changed the code as following way, for avoid the re initialization of the grid, and now its working fine.

```
var myDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: [
                        { ID: '1001', FirstName: 'Alphy', LastName: 'LastName', category: 'A', Markable: true },
                        { ID: '1002', FirstName: 'Betty', LastName: 'LastName', category: 'B', Markable: true },
                        { ID: '1003', FirstName: 'Betty', LastName: 'LastName', category: 'B', Markable: true}],
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    FirstName: { type: "string" },
                    LastName: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "FirstName",
            dir: "asc"
        },
        pageSize: 10
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        initGrid();
        loadData();
        intervalManager(true, TableStatus, 10000);            
    });
    var TableStatus = function () {
        loadData();
    }
    var refreshorderplacedgrid;
    function intervalManager(flag, animate, time) {
        if (flag)
            refreshorderplacedgrid = setInterval(animate, time);
        else
            clearInterval(refreshorderplacedgrid);
    }
    function loadData() {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").setDataSource(myDataSource);
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }
    function initGrid() {
        var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: myDataSource,
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true,
            columns: [
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "First Name"
            },
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name"
            },
            { template: kendo.template($("#isCancel-template").html()) }
        ]
        }).data("kendoGrid");
    }
```

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: For the datasource, if you're using the transport options (read/update/create/destroy), you can also use `$("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();` to refresh or re-read your data.